# Simple composer caches failes with bitbucket pipelines

Tags: composer-php, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to learn pipelines and I have built a simple 2 steps.
1. setup composer and cache it
2. build and test

**Please note that I'm building a subfolder**

I get no error but it fails.
this is what the build teardown has to say:

```
Searching for test report files in directories named [test-results, failsafe-reports, test-reports, surefire-reports] down to a depth of 4
Finished scanning for test reports. Found 0 test report files.
Merged test suites, total number tests is 0, with 0 failures and 0 errors.



image: 
 name: php:7.1.1
 run-as-user: 1

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: setup composer
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
    - step:
        name: build and test
        caches:
           - composer
        script:
          - composer global require hirak/prestissimo
          - composer install -d cms/content/
          - vendor/bin/phpunit

definitions:
  caches:
    composer: cms/content/
```

Answer (score 0):

The composer caches only cache the dependencies downloaded with `composer install`, the downloaded composer will always be removed for the next step. The best way to approach this is to put the composer actions in your first step, save the artifacts (`vendor` directory) for the next step and test your application in that step.

This would look something like this:

```
image: 
 name: php:7.1.1
 run-as-user: 1

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - composer global require hirak/prestissimo
          - composer install -d cms/content/
        artifacts:
          - cms/content/vendor/**
    - step:
        name: Test
        script:
          - vendor/bin/phpunit

definitions:
  caches:
    composer: cms/content/
```

NOTE: I also think your `vendor/bin/phpunit` should be `cms/content/vendor/bin/phpunit`